# python requests library .json() + django 500

Tags: python, django, python-requests

When I use the requests library with django and I get a 500 error back. response.json() gives me this error:

```
  response = requests.post(....)
            print("-----------------------block found!!!-----------------------")
            print(response.status_code)
            print(response.json())
```

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

Is there a way to represent a django 500 response with the requests library in a readable manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get an HTTP 500 response, You would definitely receive an empty source, Which prevents the `.json()` function from taking place.

Why not write an exception clause to handle the exceptions, like below:

---

```py
try:
    response = requests.post(....)
    print("-----------------------block found!!!-----------------------")
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.json())
except HTTPError as e:
    print('Error has occurred: ', e.response.status_code)
```